# Is it possible to activate a solution using client code in SharePoint Online 2013

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365

In SharePoint Online 2013, within code I can upload a site template (WSP) file to the solution gallery, at this point I'd like to activate the solution but I can't find any way of doing this in code.

Any ideas?

Comment: There is a powershell script for this on codeplex somewhere. At present I cannot find it, but how it works is basically mimicking the users actions to perform the task. You say Client Side do you mean JSOM or CSOM?

Comment: CSOM is preferable, I've marked Vardhaman's reply as the answer but I'd be interested in the code on codeplex, though I would suspect it would be Server side code which can definitely do it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes you can activate the solution using code in SharePoint 2013. The process is primarily for applying design packages, but they work with regular solutions too. Please have a look at the following code:

```
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Publishing;
using System;
using System.Security;

using (ClientContext context = new ClientContext("https://yoursite.sharepoint.com/sites/test/"))
{
    SecureString passWord = new SecureString();

    foreach (char c in "password".ToCharArray()) passWord.AppendChar(c);

    context.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials("yourname@yoursite.onmicrosoft.com", passWord);

    DesignPackageInfo info = new DesignPackageInfo()
    {
        PackageGuid = Guid.Empty,
        MajorVersion = 1,
        MinorVersion = 1,
        PackageName = "MyWSPPackage"
    };
    Console.WriteLine("Installing design package ");

    //Relative Path of Solution Uploaded in Solution Gallery
    string fileRelativePath = "/sites/test/_catalogs/solutions/MyWSPPackage.wsp";

    DesignPackage.Install(context, context.Site, info, fileRelativePath);
    context.ExecuteQuery();

    Console.WriteLine("Applying Design Package!");
    DesignPackage.Apply(context, context.Site, info);
    context.ExecuteQuery();
}
```

I have modified the code which was available on the following blog:
http://blog.symprogress.com/2013/07/apply-designpackage-using-client-object-model/

Comment: Really dude, if you are going to steal other peoples work and post it, make sure you a) check if it is actually doing what is required and b) give credit.

Comment: How do you mean steal other peoples work? This is the code I have used previously to successfully activate sandbox solutions. Can you please substantiate your claim? Also, although this process is primarily for applying design packages, they work with regular solutions too.

Comment: Will edit my answer to add more details.

Comment: Where does the "DesignPackage" class come from?  Is that built into the CSOM?

Comment: It is part of the `Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Publishing` dll. Will update the answer with that thanks.

Comment: Does this require Publishing feature to be enabled on the site? I'm getting the following error: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Publishing, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Comment: Yes, it requires the publishing features to be enabled.

Comment: Ignore my last comment, well the second part, I've now included the Publishing dll in the export. Ok, thanks, I'll give it a go with publishing enabled.

Comment: Thanks @VardhamanDeshpande, works a treat, I can confirm as well that it works without the publishing feature turned on. It does cause an error but for my purposes I can catch and swallow it, the solution is still activated. Thanks again!

Comment: Great. Thanks for the additional info. Seems they changed something behind the scenes. When I tested it couple of months back, you needed the publishing features enabled.

Answer (score 0):

Found a few commercial solutions out there with this kind of capability, including [CloudPower/CloudPrep](http://blog.liquidmercurysolutions.com/blog/bid/334429/Anouncing-CloudPrep-2014-Migration-Toolkit-for-SharePoint-Online).
There's also a set of [PSM1 PowerShell modules on CodePlex](https://sharepointpowershell.codeplex.com/) that includes this ability.